# Ajax with Wordpress update_post_meta always giving 0 with response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to do update_post_meta function using Ajax and trying to pass value to database when the toggle is changed. But when Ajax is ran it always producing 0 as the response. Code is below please let me know where should i rectified.

jQuery

```
jQuery('.completed').change(function() {
        post_id = jQuery(this).data('postid');
        if(this.checked) {
            var status = "on";
        } else {
            var status = "off";
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: wpb_ajax_url,
            data: 'action=switch_toggle_post&post_id='+post_id+'&status='+status,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data){
                alert('Saved');
            }
        });      
 });
```

PHP

```
/* switch Toggle */
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_switch_toggle_post', 'switch_toggle_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_switch_toggle_post', 'switch_toggle_post');
function switch_toggle_post(){
    add_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_status', $status, true ) || update_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_status', $status);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was i missed to retrieve variables passed in ajax in the php function. Finally managed to get it sorted changing the PHP code as follows.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_switch_toggle_post', 'switch_toggle_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_switch_toggle_post', 'switch_toggle_post');
function switch_toggle_post(){
    $post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
    $post_status=$_POST['status'];
    $edit_key = '_edit_status';
    if ( ! update_post_meta ( $post_id, $edit_key, $post_status) ) { 
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $edit_key, $post_status, true );   
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: wpb_ajax_url,
```

Replace the url code with the below code

```
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
```

Comment: i dont think that is the issue beacuse ajax url is defined anyway.. but i'll give a try and will update u here

Comment: Okay then check what error coming on your console and let me know.

Comment: i posted the answer below